# JS "... is not a constructor" mystery

Tags: javascript

I'm confused at this point and I did searched for a solution but couldn't quite find the one answers my situation. Here is the code block I'm having trouble with

```
this.render = function() {
    this.$el.html(Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html()));
    itemListView = new ItemListView();
    itemListView.setItems(items);
    $('.content', this.$el).html(itemListView.$el);
    return this;
};
```

It runs flawlessly the first time. But when I navigate back to this from other page

```
itemListView = new ItemListView();
```

section gives me a "ItemListView is not a constructor" error!
This is what ItemListView looks like

```
var ItemListView = function () {

  var service = new DataService();
  var items = [];

  this.initialize = function() {
      this.$el = $('<div/>');
      this.render();
  };

  this.viewAll = function() {
      items = service.viewall();
      this.render();
  }

  this.setItems = function(list) {
      items = list;
      this.render();
  }

  this.render = function() {
      this.$el.html(Handlebars.compile($("#item-list-tpl").html())(items));
      return this;
  };

  this.initialize();

  }
```

Now why would it run the first time but not the next time?

Comment: In the second code block, it it `ItemView` (as you've written) or `ItemListView` ?

Comment: p.s. don't forget to use `var` on your local variables, e.g. `var itemListView = new ItemListView()` !

Comment: sorry, pasted from wrong file. Corrected the now.

Comment: Tried using var before but no success.

Comment: My first suspicion would be that `ItemListView` is not the same function on the second run (and probably not even a function at all since it is not common to produce functions that are not constructors, pre-ES6.)  Try adding a debugger to your `render` function and inspecting the value of `ItemListView` on the second call.

Comment: Thanks Noah Freitas. Your comment lead me to inspect more and silly me, looks like on the other page I used a variable with the same name as ItemListView and that's what was causing of the problem.